# How to create an image of a symmetric dot pattern in MATLAB/Python?

Tags: python, matlab, symmetry

Goals:

- Make images of symmetric and asymmetric dot patterns.
- Symmetric images with vertical mirror symmetry (left and right sides mirror)
- Asymmetric images made from the symmetric images (shuffling left and right sides)

I want to make a ton of these, but having trouble coming up with with the framework. Currently attempting to use MATLAB or Python to generate the images, but alternatives solutions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `fliplr` and `flipud` when concat arrays:

```matlab
% image size
sz = 100;
% random half of horizontal symmetry
Ah = rand(sz,sz/2);
% horizontal mirroring
Bh = [Ah,fliplr(Ah)];
% random half of vertical symmetry
Av = rand(sz/2,sz);
% vertical mirroring
Bv = [Av;flipud(Av)];
% show
subplot(121);
imshow(Bh);
title('horizontal symmetry')
subplot(122);
imshow(Bv);
title('vertical symmetry')
```

[image]